# I'm trying to make a blackjack game with python, and every time I draw an ace, it returns 10 instead of the value I assigned to it which is 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, blackjack

I'm new to Python and I'm very open to any criticism and tips, it would help me a lot. I've also realized that changing the value I've assigned to 'Ace' still returns 10 and I can't find the root of the problem. I also tried interchanging the position of if
player_card.value[0] == '10' or 'Jack' or 'Queen' or 'King':
player_card.count = 10 with if player_card.value[0] == 'Ace':
player_card.count = 11 and still no luck. I also tried using elif instead of just if's but as I expected, it didn't help. I haven't looked into other people's codes/videos in coding a blackjack game because I wanted to make it from scratch and to test my mastery on Python.

```
import random
import itertools as it


def player_card():
    player_card.drawn_card = random.choice(deck.cards)
    deck.cards.remove(player_card.drawn_card)
    player_card.value = player_card.drawn_card.split()
    if player_card.value[0] == '2':
        player_card.count = 2
    if player_card.value[0] == '3':
        player_card.count = 3
    if player_card.value[0] == '4':
        player_card.count = 4
    if player_card.value[0] == '5':
        player_card.count = 5
    if player_card.value[0] == '6':
        player_card.count = 6
    if player_card.value[0] == '7':
        player_card.count = 7
    if player_card.value[0] == '8':
        player_card.count = 8
    if player_card.value[0] == '9':
        player_card.count = 9
    if player_card.value[0] == 'Ace':
        player_card.count = 11
    if player_card.value[0] == '10' or 'Jack' or 'Queen' or 'King':
        player_card.count = 10

#the dealer card funtion is just the same as the player card so I didn't bother placing it here

def first_phase():
    player_card()
    first_phase.player_count = player_card.count
    print(f'Player was dealt the {player_card.drawn_card}')
    dealer_card()
    first_phase.dealer_count = dealer_card.count
    print(f'Dealer deals himself a {dealer_card.drawn_card}, Dealer Count: {first_phase.dealer_count}')
    player_card()
    print(player_card.count)
    print(player_card.value[0])
    first_phase.player_count += player_card.count
    print(f'Player was dealt the {player_card.drawn_card}, Player Count: {first_phase.player_count}')
```

Comment: ``if player_card.value[0] == '10' or 'Jack' or 'Queen' or 'King':`` does not do what you might think it does

Comment: BTW an ace is not necessarily 11.

Comment: @KlausD. yeah but I'm trying to keep it simple for now, I'm saving the refinements after I make 11 work.